# Printing object properties with JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, alert

here's my code, I was trying to print the price property of worker and soldier objects

```js
var army = [worker, soldier];

var worker={
 name:'Worker',
 price : 10,
 ammount : 0,
 award:0,
 //award : 5/11,
 time : 1000,
 defense: 10,
 attack: 5
}

var soldier={
 name:'Soldier',
 price : 50,
 ammount : 0,
 award:0,
 //award : 0.75,
 time : 1000,
 defense: 30,
 attack: 15
}

for (var i=0; i<army.length; i++){
 alert(this.price);
}
```

Do you have any idea how can I get into price property of these objects?

Comment: console.log(this) will show you why it does not work. It should be `army[i].price`

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning undefined variables to the army array, before the objects are initialized. Move that first line to after the worker and soldier.

Also, the variable `this` in a for-loop doesn't refer to anything. Use `army[i]` instead, or you could assign `var this = army[i];`.

```js
var worker = {
  name: 'Worker',
  price: 10,
  ammount: 0,
  award: 0,
  //award : 5/11,
  time: 1000,
  defense: 10,
  attack: 5
}

var soldier = {
  name: 'Soldier',
  price: 50,
  ammount: 0,
  award: 0,
  //award : 0.75,
  time: 1000,
  defense: 30,
  attack: 15
}

var army = [worker, soldier];

for (var i = 0; i < army.length; i++) {
  alert(army[i].price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the `army` array *after* you create the other arrays:

```
var army = [worker, soldier];
```

Then use `army[i]` to get the price from each object:

```
for (var i=0; i<army.length; i++){
    alert(army[i].price);
}
```